# Beamer: numbering and referencing of captions doesn't work (follow-up question)

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I desire that slides in `beamer` presentations have own `framesubtile`s. For this @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz help me with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708156). It fulfil my basic request, but now I discover, that at figures in my presentation (which are numbered on request of audience) which are in "slides `\only<+>{\framesubtitle{...} <slide content>}` doesn't increment caption numbers and referencing this figures anywhere in presentation doesn't work.

MWE, which demonstrate my problem, is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\newcounter{bar}
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \setcounter{bar}{\insertframeendpage}%
  \addtocounter{bar}{-\insertframestartpage}%
  \addtocounter{bar}{1}%
  (\slideinframe/\thebar)%
}
\makeatother



\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Foo \foo}
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Bar}
\lipsum[1][1-3], see figure \ref{fig:ena}
    \begin{figure}%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure ena}
\label{fig:ena}
    \end{figure}
        }
        \only<+>{
            \framesubtitle{Baz}
\lipsum[1][4-7], see figure \ref{fig:dva}
    \begin{figure}%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure dva}
\label{fig:dva}
    \end{figure}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result after three times of compilation is:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use two frames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could exclude the `figure` counter from being reset like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

% Remove the figure counter from the list of counters that are reset after each overlay.
% modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15089/36296
\makeatletter
\def\donotresetfigures{{%
    \let\@@elt\relax
    \def\@elt##1{%
        \expandafter\ifx\csname ##1\endcsname\c@figure%
        \else%
            \@@elt {##1}%
        \fi%
    }%
    \edef\beamer@overlaycounterresets{\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
    \let\@elt\relax%
    \def\@@elt{\@elt}%
    \xdef\beamer@overlaycounterresets{\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
}}
\donotresetfigures
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \only<+>{
           see figure \ref{fig:ena}
            \begin{figure}
              \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
              \caption{Figure ena}
              \label<.>{fig:ena}
            \end{figure}
        }
        \only<+>{
          see figure \ref{fig:dva}
          \begin{figure}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Figure dva}
            \label<.>{fig:dva}
          \end{figure}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Supper. This works! Thank you very much! You are really beamer magician ...

Comment: @Zarko You're welcome!